# Logging access to elements in data members of python objects

Tags: python, encapsulation

I want to be able to tell wheter a data field in my Python object was modified since some event. I thought I would implement this
using properties like the following:

```
class C(object):

    def get_scores(self):
        print 'getter'
        return self.__scores

    def set_scores(self, value):
        print 'setter'
        self.__scores = value
        self.__scoresWereChanged = True

    scores = property(get_scores, set_scores, None, None)

    def do_something(self):
        if self.__scoresWereChanged:
            self.__updateState() #will also set self.__scoresWereChanged to False
        self.__do_the_job()
```

This approach works well if `scores` is immutable, but it `scores` is a list and I change a single element in it, the approach fails:

```
In [79]: c.scores = arange(10)
setter

In [80]: print c.scores
getter
Out[80]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [81]: c.scores[3] = 999
getter #setter was not called
```

I can solve this by

```
In [84]: s = c.scores
getter

In [85]: s[3] = 2222

In [86]: c.scores = s
setter
```

but, of course this will not be as ellegant as I would like to.

Comment: could `__getattribute__` help you? It intercepts access to all attributes of an object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done - 
I can think of a complicated way, where each assignment to a "guarded" property would create a dynamic wrapper class to the object being stored. That class would monitor access to any "magic" method on the object (that is __setitem__, __setattr__, __iadd__, __isub__, and so on).

Creating such a class dynamically is fun, but tricky, and tricky to work right for every situation.

Another option I can think of, is to create a copy of each guarded property, and on each read access it would check to see if the property stored is still equal its copy. If not, it would mark it as dirty.

Instead of using properties, it will be cleaner to set up a descriptor class (which implements a "property" like behavior)

```
from copy import deepcopy

class guarded_property(object):
    # self.name attribute set here by the metaclass
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, "_" + self.name, value)
        setattr(instance, "_" + self.name + "_copy", deepcopy(value))
        setattr(instance, "_" +  self.name + "_dirty", True)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return getattr (instance, "_" + self.name)

    def clear(self, instance):
        setattr(instance, "_" +  self.name + "_dirty", False)
        setattr(instance, "_" + self.name + "_copy", deepcopy(self.__get__(instance, None)))

    def dirty(self, instance):
        return getattr(instance, "_" +  self.name + "_dirty") or   not (getattr(instance, "_" + self.name + "_copy") == self.__get__(instance, None))


class Guarded(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict_):
        for key, val in dict_.items():
            if isinstance(val, guarded_property):
                val.name = key
                dict_[key + "_clear"] = (lambda v: lambda self: v.clear(self))(val)
                dict_[key + "_dirty"] = (lambda v: property(lambda self: v.dirty(self)))(val)
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dict_)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    class Example(object):
        __metaclass__ = Guarded
        a = guarded_property()

    g =  Example()
    g.a = []
    g.a_clear()
    print g.a_dirty
    g.a.append(5)
    print g.a_dirty
    g.a_clear()
    print g.a_dirty
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd say there isn't any easy solution for that.

If you plan to use lists, as in your example, then you'll need to subclass `list` and, at least, provide your own implementation of the `__setitem__` method to allow the list changes to be monitored. For a complete example in which other methods are also overwritten, please have a look at the [urwid library](http://excess.org/urwid/) code. In particular, `monitored_list.MonitoredList` implements something similar.

In addition to this, you might want to have a look at alternative ways to define properties in your code that provide notification events when the properties are updated like [traits](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) or [gobject](http://code.enthought.com/projects/traits/) (really old tutorial, but still good to get the idea).